# Wireless Network card Disconnection while running 4+ VirtualBox instances(bridged)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I am running several VMs with VirtualBox using Vagrant to configure and control my test env. Host box is Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I am using a WiFi connection to a Cisco WAP321 and I have the VM boxes bridged to the WiFi interface. All VMs are Linux either Ubuntu or Debian.

For some reason, not always but rather 90% of the time, when I lunch a 4th VM my wireless connection goes down(host machine), it disconnects from the AP and it is not connecting back any more until I reboot or shutdown all the VMs + disable/enable wireless network interface(and this one not always work).

I've been checking the logs, and the only thing recorded there is the AP disconnection, and the time-out to re-connect.

Would you guys give me a piece of advice on how to debug this problem? I know it is an odd setup, and that it would be better to connect via network cable but at the room I am working we run out of free network ports.

Comment: I am quite surprised you managed to bridge to Wi-Fi. This is not reliable and usually does not work at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I use vagrant/virtualbox extensively for development on my OSX laptop, and I bridge to my wifi adaptor about 50% of the time, and have never had problems. Just one bit of anecdotal evidince...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've been reading the Vagrant book from Mitchell Hashimoto and there is no mention regarding what your saying. Is it not working for you? or you have read that it is recommended to avoid bridged to wireless adapter for some reason?